# The prompt tells me that there is no module name pandas, but is already installed

Tags: python, pandas, module, path

```
pip 3 install pandas 
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\marco\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\marco\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\marco\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in c:\users\marco\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\marco\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas) (1.16.0)ù
co>pip 3.9.13 install pandas
ERROR: unknown command "3.9.13"

(base) C:\Users\marco>cd
C:\Users\marco

(base) C:\Users\marco>C:\Users\marco\OneDrive\Desktop\TDE_Sol_FOD_Recenti-20230503T193854Z-001\TDE_Sol_FOD_Recenti\fod20200131\comuniFOD.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marco\OneDrive\Desktop\TDE_Sol_FOD_Recenti-20230503T193854Z-001\TDE_Sol_FOD_Recenti\fod20200131\comuniFOD.py", line 50, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

co>pip 3.9.13 install pandas
ERROR: unknown command "3.9.13"
```

Answer (score 1):

As for unknown command, you need to write the command pip or python without white space between the command and version:

Failure command: `pip 3 install pandas`

Success command: `pip3 install pandas` or `pip3.9.13 install pandas`

As for the fact that your code does not see the library, check under which version of python you are running the code, then install your library on it. As another solution, create a virtual python environment and install all the modules you need on it and run from under it.

Comment: It doesn't work...but thank you